# Access column not found but exists java

Tags: java, base-de-datos, select, ms-access, excepciones

Cuando intento llamar una columna me marca que no la encuentra, ya verifique que efectivamente, si esta en la base de datos y que no me equivoque al escribir el nombre de la tabla y columna.
Siento que entonces me falta algo de codigo para que pueda correr bien.

```
public void cargarDatos() {
    String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/****/Documents/Repaso.accdb";
    String sql = "SELECT platillo FROM pasta";  //Consulta sql
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery (sql);

        txtMostrarNombre.setText(rs.getString(sql));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ex+"\nInténtelo nuevamente", " .::Error En la Operacion::." ,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es lo que me aparece al correrlo, ahi puse la tabla que tengo.

Lo que intento hacer es que el programa acceda al archivo de access y muestre en un txt la consulta del primer dato de la columna [Platillo]

Comment: Sabrías decir que excepción es la que se está lanzando.

Comment: A mi parecer el problema es sencillo: confusión de mayusculas(Platillo) y minusculas(platillo).

Comment: Ya lo intente como dices @Shassain, pero aun asi me sigue marcando mi mismo: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 Column not found: SELECT platillo FROM pasta